# Support for setting different 'jwk-set-uri's for each JWT in OAuth 2.0 Resource Server Multi-tenancy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

[An issue url on Spring Security github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13808)

Let me first explain about my situation.
Our service is using JWT in Resource Server issued by an Authorization Server(Let's call it S1).
Also, we should have specific jwk-set-uri which is separated from issuer.
application.yaml is like below.

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: original.server:8080/.well-known/jwks.json
          issuer-uri: https://s1.host.name
```

Now we are replacing original Authorization Server(S1) to new one(S2) for issuing.
And new issuer also has its own jwk-set-uri.
In order for backward compatibility, we should permit original JWT format(issuer & jwk-set-uri) and, at the same time, new JWT format.

I thought it can't be better if I can just list sets of information for each JWT format(issuer, jwk-set-uri, ...) in application.yaml like below.

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceservers:
        server1: # it'd be just a name developers designate
          jwt:
            jwk-set-uri: original.jwks.server:8080/.well-known/jwks.json
            issuer-uri: https://s1.host.name
        server2:
          jwt:
            jwk-set-uri: new.jwks.server:8080/.well-known/jwks.json
            issuer-uri: https://s2.host.name
```

But, I found that these kind of configuration is not possible at the moment.
It just supports one set of jwk-set-uri and issuer at the moment like below.
I can't configure multiple jwk-set-uris associating with multiple issuers with using JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver, which is for OAuth2 resource server multi-tenancy.

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: original.server:8080/.well-known/jwks.json
          issuer-uri: https://s1.host.name
```

If a solution like above is not possible right now, it'd be really nice if I can configure different 'jwk-set-uri's for each issuer with using JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver.
According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html) of it, I can just set multiple issuers, but not able to set different jwt-set-uris.

```java
JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver = new JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver
    ("https://idp.example.org/issuerOne", "https://idp.example.org/issuerTwo");

http
    .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
    )
    .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
        .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver)
    );
```

What could I achieve what I need?

Comment: It is very likely that Spring Security team will tell you that your issue is related to Spring Boot and that it should be opened there. They might also tell you that they don't really care about multi-tenancy (this is one of my motivations for maintaining an [additional Boot starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons))

Answer (score 1):

### Easy solution with a [starter of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#oidc-starter)

This starter enables to configure OAuth2 resource servers (and clients) with 0 Java conf in most cases. It is adapted to the "static" multi-tenant scenario you face, and provides with more than the `AuthenticationManagerResolver` you need: it also allows to configure authorities mapping and CORS configuration with just properties (among other things). Make sure you read the [*Risks Of Using This Libs And Mitigations*](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#drawbacks) section of the README

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity // @EnableMethodSecurity in a servlet
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

```yaml
# remove spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver properties, 
# it is not used and adapted to single tenant scenarios only
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: https://s1.host.name
          jwk-set-uri: original.jwks.server:8080/.well-known/jwks.json
          authorities:
          # this is an array: you can define as many JSON path as you need
          # you can also add basic transformation for each (prefix and force to upper / lower case)
          - path: $.json-path.to.claim.to.use.as.authorities.source
        - iss: https://s2.host.name
          jwk-set-uri: new.jwks.server:8080/.well-known/jwks.json
          authorities:
          - path: $.json-path.to.claim.to.use.as.authorities.source
        resourceserver:
          permit-all:
          - "/public/**"
```

Pretty lean and very close to what you are asking for (and works in both reactive and servlet applications).

### With just `spring-boot-starter-resource-server`

##### Edit: I wrote servlet configuration, but realize afterward that you are using `JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver` in your question. However, you still get the idea and should be able to port the following by yourself. In case of doubt, you can have a look at what I do for reactive apps in [my starter source](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oidc/starter/reactive/resourceserver/ReactiveSpringAddonsOidcResourceServerBeans.java).

You already found [the right manual chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html#oauth2resourceserver-multitenancy), You just need to customize the `AuthenticationManagerResolver` a little further. Here is approximately what "my" starter configures for you:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
            HttpSecurity http,
            ServerProperties serverProperties,
            @Value("${origins:[]}") String[] origins,
            @Value("${permit-all:[]}") String[] permitAll,
            AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> authenticationManagerResolver)
            throws Exception {

        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver));

        // Enable and configure CORS
        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource(origins)));

        // State-less session (state in access-token only)
        http.sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        // Disable CSRF because of state-less session-management
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

        // Return 401 (unauthorized) instead of 302 (redirect to login) when
        // authorization is missing or invalid
        http.exceptionHandling(eh -> eh.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Bearer realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        }));

        // If SSL enabled, disable http (https only)
        if (serverProperties.getSsl() != null && serverProperties.getSsl().isEnabled()) {
            http.requiresChannel(channel -> channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure());
        }

        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .requestMatchers(Stream.of(permitAll).map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new).toArray(AntPathRequestMatcher[]::new)).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated());
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }

    private UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(String[] origins) {
        final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(origins));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("*"));

        final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Data
    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring-addons")
    static class SpringAddonsProperties {
        private IssuerProperties[] issuers = {};

        @Data
        static class IssuerProperties {
            private URI issuerUri;
            private URI jwkSetUri;

            @NestedConfigurationProperty
            private ClaimMappingProperties[] claims;

            private String usernameJsonPath = JwtClaimNames.SUB;

            @Data
            static class ClaimMappingProperties {
                private String jsonPath;
                private CaseProcessing caseProcessing = CaseProcessing.UNCHANGED;
                private String prefix = "";

                static enum CaseProcessing {
                    UNCHANGED, TO_LOWER, TO_UPPER
                }
            }
        }

        public IssuerProperties get(URL issuerUri) throws MisconfigurationException {
            final var issuerProperties = Stream.of(issuers).filter(iss -> issuerUri.equals(iss.getIssuerUri())).toList();
            if (issuerProperties.size() == 0) {
                throw new MisconfigurationException("Missing authorities mapping properties for %s".formatted(issuerUri.toString()));
            }
            if (issuerProperties.size() > 1) {
                throw new MisconfigurationException("Too many authorities mapping properties for %s".formatted(issuerUri.toString()));
            }
            return issuerProperties.get(0);
        }

        static class MisconfigurationException extends RuntimeException {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 5887967904749547431L;

            public MisconfigurationException(String msg) {
                super(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    static class JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
        private final SpringAddonsProperties.IssuerProperties properties;

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
            return Stream.of(properties.claims).flatMap(claimProperties -> {
                Object claim;
                try {
                    claim = JsonPath.read(jwt.getClaims(), claimProperties.jsonPath);
                } catch (PathNotFoundException e) {
                    claim = null;
                }
                if (claim == null) {
                    return Stream.empty();
                }
                if (claim instanceof String claimStr) {
                    return Stream.of(claimStr.split(","));
                }
                if (claim instanceof String[] claimArr) {
                    return Stream.of(claimArr);
                }
                if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(claim.getClass())) {
                    final var iter = ((Collection) claim).iterator();
                    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
                        return Stream.empty();
                    }
                    final var firstItem = iter.next();
                    if (firstItem instanceof String) {
                        return (Stream<String>) ((Collection) claim).stream();
                    }
                    if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(firstItem.getClass())) {
                        return (Stream<String>) ((Collection) claim).stream().flatMap(colItem -> ((Collection) colItem).stream()).map(String.class::cast);
                    }
                }
                return Stream.empty();
            }).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast).toList();
        }
    }

    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    static class SpringAddonsJwtAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> {
        private final SpringAddonsProperties springAddonsProperties;

        @Override
        public JwtAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
            final var issuerProperties = springAddonsProperties.get(jwt.getIssuer());
            final var authorities = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(issuerProperties).convert(jwt);
            final String username = JsonPath.read(jwt.getClaims(), issuerProperties.getUsernameJsonPath());
            return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, username);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest>
            authenticationManagerResolver(SpringAddonsProperties addonsProperties, SpringAddonsJwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter) {
        final Map<String, AuthenticationManager> authenticationProviders = Stream.of(addonsProperties.getIssuers()).collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        issuerProperties -> issuerProperties.getIssuerUri().toString(),
                        issuerProperties -> toAuthenticationManager(authenticationProvider(
                                issuerProperties.getJwkSetUri().toString(),
                                issuerProperties.getIssuerUri().toString(),
                                authenticationConverter))));
        return new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver((AuthenticationManagerResolver<String>) authenticationProviders::get);
    }

    static JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(String jwkSetUri, String issuer, SpringAddonsJwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter) {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri).build();
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer));

        var provider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder);
        provider.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
        return provider;
    }
    
    static AuthenticationManager toAuthenticationManager(JwtAuthenticationProvider provider) {
        return provider::authenticate;
    }
}
```

```yaml
# remove spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver properties, 
# it is not used and adapted to single tenant scenarios only
allowed-origins: http://localhost:4200
permit-all: /public/**
spring-addons:
  issuers:
  - issuer-uri: https://s1.host.name
    jwk-set-uri: original.jwks.server:8080/.well-known/jwks.json
    claims:
    - jsonPath: $.json-path.to.claim.to.use.as.authorities.source
  - issuer-uri: https://s2.host.name
    jwk-set-uri: new.jwks.server:8080/.well-known/jwks.json
    claims:
    - jsonPath: $.json-path.to.claim.to.use.as.authorities.source
```

Not as flexible as with "my" starter, and quite more verbose...